# Retrieving Magento Product Info from Solr

Tags: magento, solr

I'm working on an application where we need Magento to push all products to solr so we can retrieve them directly from there. That means we use the Solr REST API to retrieve products that have been pushed by Magento.

I followed the steps described here: http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/magento-apache-solr-integration

The settings work fine, the products are pushed to solr and I can retrieve them via the REST API as expected. The only fields, however that i can retrieve from solr are: status, timestamp, store_id, id, short_description, sku, price, name, in_stock,description_en, fulltext_en, attr_select_tax_class_id, attr_select_status.

According to the schemas.xml, I should be able to get the following additional fields: "visibility", "show_in_categories", "categories".

Unfortunately this is not the case. I even added the attribiute stored="true" to these fields, without any visible result. The question is, how do  I make these fields show up in the search results? My query typically looks as follows:

```
 http://solr:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

In addition, I would like to retrieve other Magento attributes (e.g. custom design, product tags, product reviews, etc.). Is there a way this can be done?

thanks.
Max.

Answer (score 1):

Magento will only index attributes within Solr which are searchable and used in product listing. This means that all the product attributes which are *not* meant to be searched (not in quick search, nor advanced search) will *not* be indexed within Solr.

If you want to add specific attributes to the index, you can make them searchable. To do so, login into your administration panel and do the following:

1. Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes
2. Select the attribute(s) you want to index within Solr and click on it
3. Under "Frontend Properties" set "Use in Advanced Search" and "Used in Product Listing" to Yes
4. Go to Index Management, and recreate the indices

Unfortunately Magento will sometimes index only references and not the actual values itself. So unless you are loading the index within Magento, some of the information might not be useful. We are currently using the Solr index to enable a Magento product search within Drupal with the help of Search API, Search API Solr and Sarnia, which is the reason we wanted to modify which attributes are indexed, however having sometimes only references complicates the output.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the fields, you need to use the [fl parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl).

fl parameter controls the fields which would be returned back with the response.
Try `fl=*` which would return all the fields marked as stored.

```
http://solr:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&fl=*
```

You can customise the fields by putting them individually.

```
fl=visibility,show_in_categories,categories
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the problems. The configuration in Magento showed that the product is not in stock. As a result the fields "visibility", "show_in_categories", "categories".where not showing up in solr. After setting the products as in stock, they now appear.

The second part of my question remains unanswered: how do i get fields such as image, url, keywords to show up in solr? Using SOAP, there are much more fields that are included in a product. I'm trying to get all these into solr.  Any input would be much appreciated.